# More than 254 client IPs in PPTP (PPTPD)

Tags: vpn, pptp, pptpd

I'm trying to setup my PPTP to allow more than 255 client connections.

I have added the connections param in pptpd.conf to allow the connections but I do not know how to set the remoteip specification to allow more than 255 addresses.

Currently I have:

```
remoteip 192.168.0.2-255
```

This allows 254 client connections but I really want to set this so I can have up to 500 or more. Something like:

```
remoteip 192.168.0-10.2-255
```

But this is not valid, I get the error

```
 MGR: Bad IP address (192.168.0-10.2-255) in config file!
```

Can anyone suggest how this should be done in the config file?

Thanks

NOTE:

I've had a good look through the man page for the config file and cannot see any examples of how this would be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
remoteip 192.168.0.2-254,192.168.1.2-254
```

The annotation in the pptpd.conf file is weird.

Comment: thanks.. just what I needed except that there can be no space after the comma.. i.e. remoteip 192.168.0.2-254,192.168.1.2-254